# Is there any way to recover Streamfield data that was lost due to lack of migration?

Tags: django, postgresql, wagtail, django-migrations, wagtail-streamfield

I pushed changes to StreamFields in my models (i.e., adding new block types) without creating Migrations, as [specified in the docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/streamfield_migrations.html). This resulted in a large loss of user data, and unfortunately there isn't a recent database backup.

If I were to go digging in a copy of the current Postgres database, would I be able to find the lost user data in the version history somehow? I'm also open to any other suggestions about how to recover the lost data, if possible.

Comment: Would you be able to recover the lost data? Most likely not. Without a reliable backup your data is gone, even if you had immediately shut down the database.  You can *restore* from the latest backup but that will not get anything later and may reintroduce legitimately deleted and undo updates. Worth it? Lessons: 1. Always assume your changes will fail in some way. 2. Always push changes from Development into a Test environment first. 3. Before pushing to Production **make a backup**.

Answer (score 0):

From your question is not really clear what you did:

1. Did you add/edit block to `StreamField`? In most cases should not remove data
2. Did you migrate `RichTextFields` to `StreamField`? This indeed very likely replaced existing data

But in any case first check database and especially `wagtailcore_revision` table. It has `content` field which is json copy of all fields of the current page.